# Is private key sent out at any ocassion in a request to any RPC?

Tags: signature, private-key, rpc, external-api, api

Do I understand correnctly that **no RPC** whether it be the standard Ethereum full node, or an RPC/REST API gateway, require a private key to be sent to it in **the pure text?** A private key is only used to sign some RPC calls or transactions locally?

Why can't a **third-party RPC**, service, the likes of Infura, take any of my transactions and re-send it on my behalf any time it may want to, for any reason?   In a malicious way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A private key is only used to sign some RPC calls or transactions locally?

Only locally.

> Why can't a third-party RPC service take any of my transactions and re-send it on my behalf any time it may want to, for any reason?

RPC services re-send your transactions using `eth_sendRawTransaction` API.

Comment: `RPC services re-send your transactions using eth_sendRawTransaction API.` -- the question isn't "how"? It's "if an third-party RPC gateway,  Infura, for instace, sent my previous TX again, on my behalf, in a malicious way". After all, a TX has already been signed by me and a third-party RPC has saved it in a DB.

Comment: There seems to be lack of understanding on your behalf of Ethereum works. After the transaction has been broadcasted to peer-to-peer network it cannot be undoed or modified. Nonce prevents reusing the same transaction again. Nothing happens if the transaction is send again, because it can change the EVM state only once.

Comment: As a general advise, people have been building cryptocurrencies for a decade. Trivial issues like this are well addressed and covered.

Comment: You've misunderstood my question twise. Once again: if a TX gets resent ON BEHALF on a user BY a THIRD-PARTY RPC service. With a nonce increamented.

Comment: Namely, a user send 10 ETH to somehow, via third-party RPC gateway-service. Then a RPC gateway-service takes his TX, increments nonce and sends it again. Can this be done? Or is nonce embedded into a signed TX and therefore a new TX can't be created without a private key?

Comment: With a malicious intent

Comment: You answered your own question: Yes, nonce is embedded in the transaction.

Comment: WHAT?? What are you here for then?

Comment: Why did Luke Skywalker need Yoda?